# Remove Decimal Place Values in Legend of Plotly Radar Graph?

Tags: python, plotly

Here is the graph I have:

[image: current_graph]

...and here is the graph I want, without the decimal places:

[image: desired_graph]

...and here is the code I have for the graph:

```
import plotly.express as px
from pandas import DataFrame

# The data
data = {"r": [3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2],
        "theta": ['Python', 'Java', 'VBA', 'C#', 'C++', 'C']}

# Convert to DF
df = DataFrame(data)
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True, markers=True, range_r=(0,3))
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')

# Update the font of the graph
fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(
        family="Calibri",
        size=24,  # Set the font size here
        color="Black",
    )
)

# Display the graph and save it
# fig.write_html("graphs/programming_languages.html")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an arbitrary scale, specify the scale value in a list in the layout settings. Alternatively, you can specify the scale interval. In this case, the interval value is 1.

```
fig.layout.polar.radialaxis.tickvals = [0,1,2,3]
#fig.layout.polar.radialaxis.dtick = 1
```

[image]